A corollary of Frisch-Waugh-Lowell Theorem
The formulation is just a special case of FWL. Say we have a partitioned regression, $Y=X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2+\epsilon$ but with $X_2$ be $n\times 1$ and $\beta_2$ a constant.
Let $b_1,b_2$ be two OLS estimators of $\beta_1,\beta_2$ by regressing $Y$ on $X_1,X_2$. $\tilde \beta_1$ be ols estimator when regress $Y$ on $X_1$ only, and $\delta$ be estimator when regress $X_2$ on $X_1$.
We want to show $\tilde\beta_1=b_1+\delta b_2$.
I think this should be a corollary of FWL, and I can write out the values of these coefficients using matrix multiplications of $X_1,X_2,Y$, but I don't know what to do next. Should I just try to manipulate matrices? But I can't get to the result.
